# Django Form View: M to M values not saved

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I have following setup in my Django App:

**views**

```
class LearningObjectiveView( LoginRequiredMixin, FormView ):
  form_class = LearningObjectiveForm
  success_url = reverse_lazy( 'learning_objective' )
  template_name = 'learningobjective.html'

  def get_context_data( self, **kwargs ):
    trainee = Trainee.objects.get( username = self.request.user )
    context = super( LearningObjectiveView, self ).get_context_data( **kwargs )
    context['learningobjective'] = LearningObjective.objects.filter( trainee = trainee.id )
    context['topic'] = Topic.objects.filter( trainee = trainee.id )
    return context

  def form_valid( self, form ):
    self.object = form.save( commit = False )
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
      self.object.trainee = Trainee.objects.get( username = self.request.user )
    self.object.save()
    return super( LearningObjectiveView, self ).form_valid( form )
```

**models**

```
class Topic( models.Model ):
  trainee = models.ForeignKey( Trainee )
  topic = models.TextField()

class LearningObjective( models.Model ):
  trainee = models.ForeignKey( Trainee )
  topic = models.ManyToManyField( Topic, blank = True, null = True )
  learning_objective = models.TextField()
```

**forms**

```
class LearningObjectiveForm( ModelForm ):
  class Meta:
    model = LearningObjective
    fields = ( 'learning_objective', 'topic', )
```

**template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block body %}

<table border="1">
 <th>Delete</th>
 <th>Lernziel</th>
 <th>Thema</th>
 {% for learningobj in learningobjective %}
  <tr>
   <td><a href="{% url 'learning_objective_delete' pk=learningobj.pk %}">Delete</a></td>
   <td>{{ learningobj.learning_objective }}</td>
   <td>{% for t in learningobj.topic.all %}{{ t.topic }}{% endfor %}</td>
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'learning_objective_create' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Speichern"/>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Do you guys know why this is not working as expected?

When I submit my form I receive nothing as Error and just the learning objective gets created but not the topics.

**Edit** I used this kind of approach for many models now. Every field gets an entry except the many to many fields. They remain empty when submitting the form.

A part from my `self.request`:

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'topic': [u'2'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'362xs1yPTk84nXencmqxuXkKKaq5ARKF'], u'learning_objective': [u'weq']}>,
```

Since this is a queryset, can I somehow get the values of it and save it in my `FormView`? Does really nobody know how I could fix this :/ ?

Comment: How would you know if you got an error? You don't show any of the form fields or errors on your template. The form is almost certainly invalid, but you never tell the user that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how saving with `commit=False` works, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> Another side effect of using commit=False is seen when your model has a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data.

The solution is to call `form.save_m2m()`, which is a method that is added to your form instance when the form's `save` method is called with `commit=False`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        self.object.trainee = Trainee.objects.get(username=self.request.user)
    self.object.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return super(LearningObjectiveView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Ah sorry, the method is added to the form, not the object.

Answer (score 0):

The code here seems a bit incorrect, few updates that could help you trace the issue are:

- In your CreateModel view define: form_class = LearningObjectiveForm, model = LearningObjective
- Use form as mentioned here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually in your template
- Again remove super call from the form_valid method of CreateModel View as this will call form.save() again(might create a duplicate object here)
- I am not sure if I see the relevance of RetrieveLearningObjective View.